# in cloud window.ehtereumundefined,in local window.ehtereum is object

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js, javascript

I am developing a dapp now, deploy the dapp in local PC, it can connect with browser extension, window.ehtereum is Object, but deploy it in aws cloud, it cann't connect with browser extension, window.ehtereum is undefine,

much thanks to any ideal of fixing this issue.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The RPC provider `window.ethereum` is injected by the browser using wallet extension or its own implementation.

When running as a service outside a browser the object `window` doesn't exists. To access web3/etherjs from a backend service you have to use an external provider, for example infura, alchemy, etc. Or establish communication between backend and frontend to use a wallet provided by the user, metamask, walletconnect, etc.